# Function create_function is deprecated in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, deprecated

The function create_function has been deprecated as of PHP 7.2. Worked previously in PHP 5 but after updating PHP crashes.

```
$func = create_function('$atts, $content = null','return "<div class=\"' . $class_list . '\">" . do_shortcode($content) . "</div>";' );
add_shortcode($shortcode, $func);
}
```

Can anyone help me in fixing my code?

Comment: You pass in `$atts` but don't use it and you use `$class_list` but you don't pass it in.

Comment: A lot of missing stuff from this example, makes it a bit more confusing than it should be... as it looks like you just want to assign $func an anonymous function. Which is more native now in php 7.

Comment: What is the error you get when it crashes?

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 5.3, the preferred way to do this has been with anonymous functions. To capture the value of an external variable, use a `use` declaration. So it should be:

```
$func = function($atts, $content = null) use ($class_list) {
    return "<div class='$class_list'>" . do_shortcode($content) . "</div>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [Anonymous Function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead.

In your question, the arguments and the vars used in the code don't seem to match up. Perhaps `$class_list` is in the parent scope? But what about `$atts` then? So, I've assumed you actually wanted to pass `$class_list`. Adjust accordingly.

```
$func = function($class_list, $content = null)
{
    return "<div class='$class_list'>" . do_shortcode($content) . "</div>"; 
}

add_shortcode($shortcode, $func);
```

Comment: Since `$class_list` isn't passed as a parameter, maybe it should be `use($class_list)`?

Comment: Yes, it the OP's code is accurate. Between us, we seem to have the bases covered -  except for `$atts`. Why is it passed and not used? A better explanation of the context would answer many questions.